# php form saves only the last input field value

Tags: php

I have a simple table "Exams" with the columns id, title and a form with a variable amount of exam input fields.

But when one submit the form the last value will be saved triple times.

I suppose it's because of the $sql_insert statement with the same value.

How can i change the code that the different values are submitted in that $sql_insert statement?

```
echo '<form action="" method="post">';
    for ($i = 1; $i <= $student['passed_exams']; ++$i) {
        echo '<label>Exams '.$i.' :</label>';
        echo '<input type="text" id="id['.$i.']" name="title" placeholder="passed Exam" />';
        echo '<br />';
    }
echo '<input type="submit" value=" Submit " name="submit" /></form>';

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    for ($i = 0; $i < $student['passed_exams']; ++$i) {
      $sql_insert = "INSERT INTO exams (title) VALUES ('".$_POST['title']."')";
      $dbConnection->query($sql_insert);
    }
    $dbConnection->close();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Php needs name as an array

```
echo '<form action="" method="post">';
    for ($i = 1; $i <= $student['passed_exams']; ++$i) {
        echo '<label>Exams '.$i.' :</label>';
        echo '<input type="text" id="id['.$i.']" name="title['.$i.']" placeholder="passed Exam" />';
        echo '<br />';
    }
echo '<input type="submit" value=" Submit " name="submit" /></form>';

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    for ($i = 0; $i < $student['passed_exams']; ++$i) {
      $sql_insert = "INSERT INTO exams (title) VALUES ('".$_POST['title'][$i]."')";
      $dbConnection->query($sql_insert);
    }
    $dbConnection->close();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to make the title array first as

```
 name="title['.$id.']"
```

Then you have to save it as

```
$_POST['title'][$id]
```